# how to open a file by fileID and then use BackupRead API?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, backup, ntfs

I'd like to open up a file by ID and then use the resulting handle in the Win32 API `BackupRead()`

Is this possible? I'm not certain if its 'okay' to use handles that come from `NtCreateFile()` in other Win32 APIs?

For example,  may I do this

```
NtCreateFile(&handle, ..., FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID, ....)
BackupFile(handle, ....)
```

I'm somewhat bothered by using `NtCreateFile`,  it's well documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  but they also mention compatibility problems could occur

Any ideas?

Comment: Just simple curiosity : since you want to backup files opened by ID, are you developing a backup tool that scans the MFT and/or USN journal? If yes, we are sharing common goals!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have 100% understood what your problem is, and I don't know any function named `BackupFile()`.

If what you want is reusing handles from `NTCreateFile()` with **`BackupRead()`**, it should be perfectly fine to do so, provided the file handle was opened with the right flags & permissions.

Be sure to call `NTCreateFile` with the `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` flag:

```
NtCreateFile(&handle, ..., FILE_OPEN_BY_FILE_ID|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT, ....)
```

If you plan to pass the resulting handle to `BackupRead()`.